# How can I hook into an authentication callback during the login process with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Using meteor, I'd like to be able to augment a `user` record after they've logged in (authenticated) with an external service to get their authorization claims.

**Update**
I am using the `{{loginButtons}}` handlebars helper widget.

Currently, I see an `Accounts.validateNewUser` and an `Accounts.onCreateUser` that can be hooked into during the creation of a new user. These would be helpful initially, but my need is recurrent.

I understand that there is the `allow` function that hangs off the `Meteor.Collection` as a means of authorizing a user's access to the collection -- which is precisely where I would use the `claims` that I intend to augment the user with to determine authorization.

Does anyone know of a hook during the login process that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to get around the lack of a callback is to use the relevant reactive variable:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    // do something when they've just logged in.
  }
});
```

The context setup by `autorun` will only re-run when the value of `Meteor.userId()` changes -- i.e. when they login.

Comment: Now that would be `Deps.autorun(function...`

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm getting Meteor.userId() should only be called in a Method.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Meteor 0.7.2 version, there's a server side hook available :
[Accounts.onLogin()](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_onlogin)

Comment: This can be called anywhere (at least in Meteor 1.1)

Answer (score 1):

From the Meteor docs on [login with password](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithpassword) there appears to be a callback already in place for what you need to do:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, [callback])
```

> **callback** Function
>   Optional callback. Called with no arguments on
>   success, or with a single Error argument on failure.

The login callback is supported for both Meteor and [external authentication services](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice).

Answer (score 0):

@Makita, thank you for the answer. I did see that `callback` param but what I failed to mention in my question was that I had no low-level hook to it because I am using the `{{loginButtons}}` handlebar helper to inject the user management widget (which is way awesome).

The problem with this approach was that I did not have access to a callback after authentication happened, so I created this pull request which I hope will be merged to solve the issue:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/479

With this, you should be able to call:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    onSuccess: function (err) {
        //perform addl authorization on Meteor.user() here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For people coming to this in 2014, You can use the [onLogin callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin) server side

Accounts.onLogin((obj)->
  user = ob.user
)

Answer (score 0):

For the accepted answer, there was an issue on page reload that messed up that solution. I ended up doing something like this (Its using angular meteor but you should get the gist, just substitute autorun for Tracker)

```
.run(function($meteor,$rootScope,$state,$localstorage){
$meteor.autorun($rootScope, function(){
    var id = Meteor.userId();
    if(id == undefined || id == null){
        id = '';
    }
    if($localstorage.get('user_id','') != id){
        $localstorage.set('user_id',id);
        if(Meteor.userId()){
            //On login
            $state.go('profile',{user_id: Meteor.userId()});
        }else{
            //On logout
            $state.go('main');
        }
    }
});
});
```

I only recommend this solution for development, when I stop using the default accounts-ui I'm going to have to implement the lower level functions and there will be no need for this.